# Microsoft Word VSTO C# - How to add the fake red curly underline visible only in edit mode under any word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to imitate the functionality from Microsoft Word "Spelling Proofing" where a red curly underline is added to misspelled words. As it is known, that red curly underline it is visible only when you edit the word document, not when you print it/save it to pdf/email it.

I want to create an add-in in C# VSTO that allows me to add those red curly underline under whatever word a user wants, a simple text input, a color selector and a button that will allow you to underline what word you want in what color you want. The catch is that I want to be able view that underline only when I am editing the document, not when I print it/save to pdf/email. Another thing is that I want to allow the user to add his own underlines ( from Microsoft Word "Home" Tab that will be normally visible when you print it.

As an upgrade for this I would love to know if it is possible to color a certain word in the same way as the above idea with underline, the color will not be available when you are not in edit mode and the same as above to allow a user to use certain colors for words from "Home" Tab.

I've tried to:
Google it, I am not pretty sure what I really need to search due my lack of knowledge in this area.
Underlines and try to play with ActiveWindow.View to make them disappear
Try to use shapes to draw an underline and then try to make them not visible to the user

Comment: Hello there. That Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineWavy is not a virtual marker only and interacts with user stack changes ( interacts with his CTRL + Z / Y). As a additional note I force the user the press a button in case he wants to remove all underlines added that way.

Yes, that squiggly thing is exactly what I am looking for. Is there any way to handle it and force it into ms-word editor?

Comment: Sadly this one requirement is limited to ms-word and vsto :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. The [Document.CheckSpelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.checkspelling) method which begins a spelling check for the specified document or range could end up with highlighted words. But there is no separate method or property for such tasks.

You need to use Windows API to draw such lines programmatically as a possible workaround.

Comment: I understand this. Not really the easiest solution, as Dmitry said in a comment that's how Grammarly ( + functionality for multiple apps ), Don't we have any workaround for this? I'm alright with any other way to visualize it, not only the underline.

Comment: There is no easy way or workaround for that - only hardcore, only Windows API :)

Comment: I've managed to do something similar with HitHighlight but it seems limited. I've needed to add as well a keylogger in order to get the "onKeyInput" event and it already seems... not right :) 
I am able to add a text in a textBox and then start writing and auto-highlight with the HitHighlight, sadly I have that flickering after every letter and I am restricting the user ctrl+f option I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported way of doing that. As far as I know, Grammarly addin for Word does something like that, but it draw directly on the screen and updates it as the user switches apps, edits, sand scrolls. Definitely not for the fainthearted.